# Joomla not executing script.php with custom component one click update

Tags: php, joomla, server, auto-update

I develop a custom component and I've created an update server to enable one click update.

When I update manually my component (`com_mediacenter`), the `script.php` works without problems but when I use `com_joomlaupdate` for one click update, I have a message that's the update works but the `script.php` is not launched.

#### update.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <extension type="component" version="3.6.2" method="upgrade">
      <name>com_mediacenter</name>
      <creationDate>August 2016</creationDate>
      <author>Me</author>
      <authorEmail>mail@mail.com</authorEmail>
      <authorUrl>http://www.***.com</authorUrl>
      <copyright>(C) 2016 - All rights reserved</copyright>
      <license>License Info</license>
      <description>Mediacenter 3.5.3</description>
      <scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
      <files folder="site">
        <folder>assets</folder>
        <filename>controller.php</filename>
        <folder>controllers</folder>
        <folder>helpers</folder>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <folder>language</folder>
        <folder>lib</folder>
        <filename>mediacenter.php</filename>
        <folder>models</folder>
        <folder>views</folder>
      </files>
      <media destination="com_mediacenter" folder="media">
        <folder>videos</folder>
      </media>
      <administration>
        <menu>COM_MEDIACENTER</menu>
        <files folder="admin">
          <filename>config.xml</filename>
          <filename>index.html</filename>
          <folder>language</folder>
          <filename>mediacenter.php</filename>
          <filename>mediacenter.xml</filename>
          <folder>sql</folder>
        </files>
      </administration>
      <updateservers>
        <server type="extension" priority="1" name="com_mediacenter">https://inwicast.me/updates/mediacenter3/mdcr_update.xml</server>
      </updateservers>
    </extension>
```

#### script.php:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class com_mediacenterInstallerScript
{
     function install( $parent ) {
         echo '<p>install</p>';
     }
     function uninstall( $parent ) {
        echo '<p>uninstall</p>';
    }
     function update( $parent ) {
        echo '<p>update</p>';
     }
     function preflight( $type, $parent ) {
        echo '<p>preflight</p>';
     }
     function postflight( $type, $parent ) {
        echo '<p>postflight</p>';
   }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I Guess version is missing from your manifest file, since version string is recorded in the components table

`<version>0.0.15</version>`